# Debugging my Android app in Delphi stopped working

Tags: android, delphi

If I make a new FM mobile app, then the debugger works fine. After ctrl-F9 to compile, I can press F8 to start the app and it stops on the

```
begin
```

just before the

```
Application.Initialise;
```

line in Project->View Source

However, when I load up the app I've been working on for a few weeks now and press F8, the debugging appears to work, then it "lets go". After that, I am not in debug mode anymore and I might as well just have done a "run without debugging."

All things other than the projects being equal then, there's something in my app that is different, that prevents the debugging on the device from working *just for that app* - or it's a bug. Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: (expletive deleted) To resolve the issue, I simply created a new FM mobile application and added all the source files to the new project. Debugging works again.

Comment: Which Delphi version and update?

Comment: XE5 Update 2. Of course, while the debugger worked for a while in the new project, it also stopped working once again. I think it had something to do with adding files in Project->Deployment, but I really still am not sure what's causing the debugger to stop working.