# Can't debug on SAMSUNG GALAXY S7 EDGE

Tags: android, delphi, debugging, delphi-10-seattle

Why I can't debug my application on SAMSUNG GALAXY S7 EDGE (ANDROID 6.0.1) in RAD STUDIO 10 Seattle upd 1?

When I debug, the application on the device starts, but the debugger in RAD STUDIO (Delphi) immediately shuts off - I can't check the variable, set break points, etc.

I tried to debug even over IP, but the result is the same.

On all other devices, debugging is OK.

Someone advise me how to solve this problem?

PS: I have enabled USB Debugging Mode

Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224419) almost 2 years ago with XE5. I haven't had it since then. Could it be that Delphi doesn't support Android 6? What version do your other devices have?

Comment: Android 5.x.x On the Internet it says it would support ANDROID 6. The application runs normally (on Android 6), but the debugger immediately disconnects.

Comment: Debug and run are 2 different things. The EMBT site says nothing about Android 6. Does the _same app_ debug on Android 5x or earlier?

Comment: Yes. The same app was debugged on Android 5.x earlier. But the same problem is also for new applications.

Comment: So the problem is only with the S7. Now it could be the device, or the Android 6. I'm going to guess it's because of the Android 6. You could download and install the Android 6.0 SDK, but Delphi 10 might not support it. This is what happens when you're on the bleeding edge: You bleed.

Comment: If you do decide you want to try this, download the 6.0 SDK from [here](http://wccftech.com/download-android-6-0-sdk/) and configure it for Delphi using instructions from [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Installing_the_Android_Development_Tools_Manually).

Comment: I have downloaded the Android 6.0 SDK and installed. Delphi 10 with no problems working with this SDK. The problem will probably be really only and only in connection DELPHI 10 and S7...

Comment: Still wondering: S7 is 64-bit. That would be the problem?

Comment: I just got an S7 myself. Was looking forward to testing with it. Good to know that Delphi has problems with it :-(

Comment: It's a big disappointment for me. I was looking forward to testing as a small child. Embarcadero somehow solves this problem?

Comment: Please file a bug report to Embarcadero using [Quality Portal](http://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: Current news: Interim solution from Embarcadero is to add the parameter-autolaunch (Run | Parameters | ). The debugger works, but it probably will not be the final solution.

Comment: See https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14033?filter=-2

Comment: FYI: Adding the parameter `-autorun` and also the hotfix mentioned in the comments of the bugreport solved this problem for Samsung Galaxy Tab A with Android 6.0.1.

Comment: @KJAN: I think you can answer your own question now. People will find the solution easier this way.

Comment: The issue was resolved on Embarcadero Quality. See https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14033?filter=-2

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by going to <kbd>Run</kbd> -> <kbd>Parameters</kbd> in RAD Studio, and add `-autolaunch` to the list of parameters.

Apparently Embarcadero also a HotFix available, but I haven't tried it yet.
The HotFix is [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30531), but is only available to members; registration is required.

Answer (score -1):

I know I'm a bit late to answer, but maybe it will help other people in future. Me too I've got a Samsung S7 Edge, and couldn't debug with it. After some checking I realized that the reason is the Knox/My Knox. See here: https://seap.samsung.com/forum-topic/can-i-use-usb-debugging-mode-device-running-knox
What I've done is just go to playstore, found there My Knox and clicked Uninstall, then switched on  USB debugging that was previously grayed out. 
There are some other manuals on how to disable Knox. Some of them require rooting, but after rooting, I believe Samsung warranty will not work, if something happens to your phone.

Comment: The issue was resolved on https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14033?filter=-2

Comment: So?? I used another (quick) solution which helped me and was totally free. If you are embrocadero member, you welcome, not everyone is. You don't need to downvote an answer only because it's different than yours.